# Writing the output of sql query to a file

Tags: java, postgresql, file-io, postgresql-copy

I have an SQL query:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || tablename
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where tablename like 'r_395%';
```

whose output is this:

```
?column?      
--------------------
 DROP TABLE r_395_0
 DROP TABLE r_395_1
 DROP TABLE r_395_2
 DROP TABLE r_395_3
 DROP TABLE r_395_4
 DROP TABLE r_395_5
 DROP TABLE r_395_6
 DROP TABLE r_395_7
 DROP TABLE r_395_8
 DROP TABLE r_395_9
(10 rows)
```

I am using entity manager to execute this query:

```
StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();

query.append("SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || tablename
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where tablename like 'r_395%'");            
entityManager.createNativeQuery(query.toString()).executeUpdate();
```

I want to write this output to a file. If it was a mere a text file I would use filewriter and buffered writer. But now it is an SQL generated file, I am a little bit confused. Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: The source of the data is unimportant.  It sounds like the output file is, indeed, a text file.

Comment: Yes, trojanfoe is right. You just have to write your data into a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you want to write a file locally (on the machine of the database) there is also the very fast and simple [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) for a case like this:

```
COPY $$SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || tablename
         FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
        WHERE tablename ~~ 'r_395%'$$ TO /path/to/myfile;
```

I use [dollar-quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) here, to avoid escaping the single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

A very similar solution to using SQL COPY (see the answer of Erwin Brandstetter) is to use the [psql meta command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) `\copy`. The difference here is that you do not need local access on the database box. The output of SQL COPY can only be written to a location on the database box where the system user postgres has write access. With psql \copy you can write the output to a location on the client.

Connect to the database with psql and execute the command

```
psql -h host -p port -U user database
\copy (SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE tablename ~~ 'r_395%') to '/path/to/myfile'
```

Or pass the command directly to psql with the -c parameter:

```
psql -h host -p port -U user -c "\copy (SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE tablename ~~ 'r_395%') to '/path/to/myfile'" database
```

HTH

Comment: You can also use \o to set an output file from psql, real easy to do.